# CDK CrossAccount Deployment AccessDenied. User doesn't have permission to call ssm:GetParameters

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, cicd, aws-codepipeline, infrastructure-as-code

I am facing issues. Trying to deploy CFN Stack in crossaccount.

I have created roles and import in my code pipeline stack.

But when I am trying to launch and comes to deploystage execution its getting error.

I am using CDK typescript.

```
const CrossAccountRole = iam.Role.fromRoleArn(this, 'ProdCrossAccountRole', `arn:aws:iam::${props.accounts.prodaccount}:role/MyCrossAccountRole`)
 
const prodAccountRootPrincipal = new iam.AccountPrincipal(props.accounts.prodaccount);

const pipeline = new codepipeline.Pipeline(this, 'MyCodePipeline', {
      pipelineName: 'MyCodePipeline', // Replace with your desired pipeline name
      artifactBucket: mybucket,
      //encryptionKey: key
    });



const CRAccdeployStage = pipeline.addStage({
      stageName: props.codepipeline.crossaccountstage,
      actions: [
        new codepipeline_actions.CloudFormationCreateUpdateStackAction({
          actionName: props.codepipeline.crossaccountaction,
          stackName: props.codepipeline.crossaccountstack,
          templatePath: new codepipeline.ArtifactPath(
            buildOutput,
            'CdkServerlessDemoStack.template.json', // Replace with the path to your synthesized CloudFormation template
          ),
          adminPermissions: true,
          runOrder: 1,
          role: CrossAccountRole,
          cfnCapabilities: [cdk.CfnCapabilities.ANONYMOUS_IAM],
          deploymentRole: CrossDeploymentRole,
          
        }),
      ],
    });
```

ERROR I FACED,

[image: ERROR]

I trust my CICD account and add administrator access policy.

Any One have Idea What I have missed?

Thank You

Comment: There is no role at the specified ARN, or maybe the role doesn't allow your account to assume it.

Comment: thanks for mentioned. I have mistakenly used passedRole instead of assumedrole. yeah Now its works.

Comment: but now getting another error like User doesn't have permission to call ssm:GetParameters.

Comment: While bootstrapping, what policy you used for `--cloudformation-execution-policies`?

Comment: That's an unrelated error, I would delete this question and open a new one

Comment: Used Administrator Access Policy @AnkushJain

Comment: @HardikPatel - When bootstrapping second account, did you add the account where CodePipeline lives as a trusted account? (See https://aws.plainenglish.io/cdk-cross-account-pipelines-3126e0434b0c for example of how to do that)

Comment: yes, I have done that also. @TofigHasanov

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this issue at my end.

Added below policy in my cross deployment role.

```
new iam.PolicyStatement({
            effect: iam.Effect.ALLOW,
            actions: [
              'ssm:GetParameter',
              'ssm:GetParameters',
              'ssm:GetParametersByPath',
            ],
            resources: [
                          "arn:aws:ssm:xxxx:xxxxxxx:parameter/*",
            ],
          }),
```